# whereto write this code correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

new to c#... I got this question and got the answer , but I am confused as to where the answer should be written  (in main or in the class itself)

**Question:**
*Given an instance circle of the following class:*

```
public sealed class Circle 
{
  private double radius;

  public double Calculate(Func<double, double> op) {
    return op(radius);
  }
}
```

write code to calculate the circumference of the circle, without modifying the Circle class itself.

**the answer is:**

```
circle.Calculate(r => 2 * Math.PI * r);
```

also what exactly the meaning of `=>` in this case

Comment: if you are new to C#, it'll benefit you to learn the basics before lambdas (`=>`) and `Func`

Comment: I read about just not confident enough about them and how to use. if you have good reference to read from it'll be great

Comment: if `Circle` is not allowed to be modified, I don't see how you'll ever obtain a result that's not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as writing an anonymous delegate

```
circle.Calculate(
    delegate (double r)
    {
        return 2 * Math.PI * r;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first things first. I don't know if you're familiar with Java or any other "common" programming language, but if you want to execute this piece of code, you must have a **main** method. You can do it inside your *Circle* class or you can create a *Main* class.

If you choose to create another class, it would be something this way:

```
public class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

Also, it's important for you to read about **Lambda expressions**: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-minutes (this => you're asking about is what gets the parameter of the lambda expression and applies it into a function. So, in your case, whatever the value of *r* is, the function will return two times PI the value of *r*, that you provided).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I failed to run it right  in main in main and so I got confused ... thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public sealed class Circle
{
    private double radius;

    public double Calculate(Func<double, double> op)
    {
        return op(radius);
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static double op(double radius)
    {
        return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Circle Object = new Circle();
        // Calculate the circumference based on the radius of the object and the op function.
        Console.WriteLine("Circumference of the Circle is: " + Object.Calculate(op));

    }    

}
```